# MS SQL Server - Join two tables where ID is equivalent to new ID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to join two tables but did not able to success

```
Test Supplier Table

SID     NAME    
1       Test
2       Test2


Test Stock Table

    ID      NewID   SupID   Qty
    1       101     1       2
    2       102     1       5
    3       103     2       6
    101             1       4
    101             1       7
    101             2       5
    103             2       10
```

The output I am looking for

```
    ID      NAME    Qty
    2       Test    5
    101     Test    13
    101     Test2   5
    103     Test2   16
```

My code is -

```
Select S.NAME, ST.ID, SUM(ST.Qty)
From Stock ST
Inner Join ST.SupID = S.SID
```

I need to combine those ID's which are matching with the new ID's with another ID's. If you see the results, I need to combine `ID 1` qty with `ID 101` because `ID 1` has new `ID 101` and no need to display `ID 1`. I have tried inner join but did not work.

Comment: You can start here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: @Alex, i have tried inner join, but did not work

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: @Alex, just i have updated my question, please have a look, i am not sure how i can combine those ids which are matching with another id's newID column

Comment: Try this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: @Alex, my issue is ID match with New id in the same table, where i am struggling now

Comment: You need to carefully read examples in the links provided. In your code, you have missed the name of the table your are joining to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you find those with NEW ID and those without NEW ID. For those with NewID, use NEWID, for those without use ID (old ID). then you use UNION ALL to combine both result and join to the Supplier table to obtain the NAME.

```
; with
cte as
(
    -- with NewID
    select  ID = NewID, SupID, Qty = sum(Qty)
    from    Stock ST
    where   exists
            (
                select  *
                from    Stock x
                where   x.ID    = ST.NewID
            )
    group by NewID, SupID

    union all

    -- without NewID
    select  ID, SupID, Qty = sum(Qty)
    from    Stock ST
    where   not exists
            (
                select  *
                from    Stock x
                where   x.ID    = ST.NewID
            )
    group by ID, SupID
)
select  c.ID, SP.NAME, Qty =  sum(Qty)
from    cte c
        inner join Supplier SP  on  c.SupID     = SP.SID
group by c.ID, SP.NAME
```

Comment: use your actual table & column name

Answer (score 0):

Start with the Stock table and join to the Supplier table (remembering to name the table in the join) and then self-left join to the IDs in the Stock table to determine if they exist or not. Then group by on whichever ID you want to keep.

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(ST2.ID, ST.ID) ID
, S.NAME NAME
, SUM(ST.Qty) Qty
FROM Stock ST
INNER JOIN Supplier S
  ON ST.SupID = S.SID
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT ID
  FROM Stock
) ST2
  ON ST.NewID = ST2.ID
GROUP BY
  COALESCE(ST2.ID, ST.ID)
, S.NAME
```

Comment: thanks for helping me, i have accept the other solution, which i is better for me